# Search for all chat messages by a particular user?

Tags: feature-request, chat, search

Is it possible to search for all messages by a particular user in the chat search, at https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?

I tried searching with the 'search for' field empty, but got no results... and with '*', the same.

Comment: note that the last *few* are available, for example: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/154854/jez?tab=recent

Comment: Thanks; that's somewhat helpful.  Unfortunately though it doesn't seem to allow me to see recent messages on StackExchange chat sites which are subdomains of stackexchange.com (eg. english.stackexchange.com), because their user profile just leads to their chat.stackexchange.com profile.

Comment: the ids can indeed change, but if you look up their chat id it should work

Comment: +1 I've wished for this more than once

Comment: +1 I started a bounty on this because I use chat all the time and I find a need for this.